# Python delete multiple element(s) in list if in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two arrays, where if an element exists in an array received from a client then it should delete the matching array in the other array. This works when the client array has just a single element but not when it has more than one.

This is the code:

```
    projects = ['xmas','easter','mayday','newyear','vacation']

    for i in self.get_arguments('del[]'):
        try:
            if i in projects:
                print 'PROJECTS', projects
                print 'DEL', self.get_arguments('del[]')
                projects.remove(i) 
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

`self.get_arguments('del[]')`, returns an array from the client side in the format:

```
[u'xmas , newyear, mayday']
```

So it reads as one element not 3 elements, as only one unicode present.

How can I get this to delete multiple elements?

EDIT: I've had to make the list into one with several individual elements.

Comment: Fist you need to know that your `if` statuement doesn't raise a `ValueError` !

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I've tried all the solutions and they don't delete multiple elements either.

Comment: can you show `get_arguments` function ?

Comment: The `get_arguments` is a `Tornado` function. I use this to get html form arguments

Comment: Please give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example doesn't have any repeated elements, it doesn't give us any clue what might be returned by `self.get_arguments('del[]')`, and it doesn't show us the desired vs. actual results, which makes it very hard to debug your code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that `remove` just removes the first element that matches. You *could* fix that by just repeatedly calling `remove` until it doesn't exist anymore—e.g., by changing your `if` to a `while`, like this:

```
while i in projects:
    print 'PROJECTS', projects
    print 'DEL', self.get_arguments('del[]')
    projects.remove(i)
```

But in general, using `remove` is a bad idea—especially when you already searched for the element. Now you're just repeating the search so you can remove it. Besides the obvious inefficiency, there are many cases where you're going to end up trying to delete the third instance of `i` (because that's the one you found) but actually deleting the first instead. It just makes your code harder to reason about. You can improve both the complexity and the efficiency by just iterating over the list once and removing as you go.

But even this is overly complicated—and still inefficient, because every time you delete from a list, you're moving all the other elements of the list. It's almost always simpler to just build a new list from the values you want to keep, using `filter` or a list comprehension:

```
arguments = set(self.get_arguments('del[]'))
projects = [project for project in projects if project not in arguments]
```

Making `arguments` into a set isn't *essential* here, but it's conceptually cleaner—you don't care about the order of the arguments, or need to retain any duplicates—and it's more efficient—sets can test membership instantly instead of by comparing to each element.

Answer (score 4):

How about `filter`?

```
projects = filter(lambda a: a not in self.get_arguments('del[]'), projects)
```

Answer (score 3):

Could try something uber pythonic like a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [i for i in projects if i not in array_two]
```

You'd have to write-over your original projects, which isn't the most elegant, but this should work.